# c/cpp project build in MS VS 2012 to be compatible with msvs 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, projects-and-solutions

I have created a c/cpp project in microsoft visual studio 2012, but the test machine has microsoft visual studio 2008, is there a way to tell visual studio 2012 to be compatible with 2008

Answer (score 1):

No. You need to maintain two different project and solution files, one for each version. The only compatibility is between Vs2010 and VS2012 (and promised for future versions too).